# Remove duplication from the Scheme function

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (merge-sorted lst1 lst2)
  (cond ((null? lst1) lst2)
        ((null? lst2) lst1)
        ((>= (car lst1) (car lst2))
         (cons (car lst2) (merge-sorted lst1 (cdr lst2))))
        (else
         (cons (car lst1) (merge-sorted (cdr lst1) lst2)))))
Output:

(merge-sorted '(1 3 4) '(2 4 5))
=> '(1 2 3 4 4 5)
```

I have to write function on lists in Scheme.
How can I fix the duplication?

Comment: Do notice, that a merge procedure should preserve duplicates. If you really need to remove them that's ok, but if you're using this as a helper procedure for merge sort, then it's incorrect to end up with less elements than at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having `>=` as one condition, you can test equality separately, whereby whenever `(car lst1)` is equal to `(car lst2)`, you would keep one of them, but remove both on your recursive call by doing:

```
(cons (car lst1)
      (merge-sorted (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))
```

For example:

```
(define (merge-sorted lst1 lst2)
  (cond
    ((null? lst1) lst2)
    ((null? lst2) lst1)
    ((> (car lst1)
        (car lst2))
     (cons (car lst2)
           (merge-sorted lst1 (cdr lst2))))
    ((< (car lst1)
        (car lst2))
     (cons (car lst1)
           (merge-sorted (cdr lst1) lst2)))
    (else
     (cons (car lst1)
           (merge-sorted (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2))))))
```

then you would have:

```
(merge-sorted '(1 3 4) '(2 4 5))
=> '(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Comment: Wait! but what happens if there's an element duplicated in both lists? This procedure should keep both elements, I think.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez by duplicated on both lists, do you mean like `(merge-sorted '(1 3 3 4) '(3 3 4 5))`?

Comment: Because my assumption was that the two lists on their own were sorted and without duplication.

Comment: @AlexanderMaru oh, wait. _that's_ what OP wants. never mind.