# Merge with no duplicates

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to implement a merge function in scheme but with no duplicates, meaning when I have for example `(merge '(1 2 8) '(2 5 6))` it should return `'(1 2 5 6 8)` and not
`'(1 2 2 5 6 8)`. My current code returns the second result:

```
(define (merge lst1 lst2)
  (cond ((null? lst1) lst2)
        ((null? lst2) lst1)
        ((>= (car lst1) (car lst2))
          (cons (car lst2) (merge lst1 (cdr lst2))))
        (else
         (cons (car lst1) (merge (cdr lst1) lst2)))))
```

Comment: What if you run into `(null? lst1)` or `(null? lst2)` and there are duplicates in the rest of one of the lists?

Comment: See [Remove duplication from the Scheme function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47447875/4739247), which discusses the same code, and the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add another clause to the `cond` statement to handle the case of equal elements separately:

```
> (define (merge lst1 lst2)
    (cond ((null? lst1) lst2)
          ((null? lst2) lst1)
          ((> (car lst1) (car lst2))
            (cons (car lst2) (merge lst1 (cdr lst2))))
          ((> (car lst2) (car lst1))
            (cons (car lst1) (merge lst2 (cdr lst1))))
          (else
           (merge (cdr lst1) lst2))))
> (merge '(1 2 8) '(2 5 6))
(1 2 5 6 8)
```

Comment: Same question as above - what if you run into (null? lst1) or (null? lst2) and there are duplicates in the rest of one of the lists?

Answer (score 0):

Since you used the racket tag, I assume you have access to racket's functions. In that case, you can do this with [`set-union`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html?q=set-union#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fset..rkt%29._set-union%29%29). The `set-union` function operates over generic sets, and a list satisfies the `generic-set?` interface. You could alternatively use [`append`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=append#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._append%29%29) and [`remove-duplicates`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=set-union#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._remove-duplicates%29%29), but `set-union` takes care of that with one call.

If you also want the resulting list to be sorted, you can use [`sort`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=sort#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._sort%29%29), using `<` as your operator.

Composing all of these together you get:

```
(define (sorted-merge lst1 lst2)
  (sort (set-union lst1 lst2) <))
```